# C# SQL Server: how to Insert into table if textbox value > 0 or !null? , using SqlCommand with parameter as values

Tags: c#, sql-server, null

I'm trying to insert textbox and labels' values into a table. I want to make this run if the values of `txtbasoC.Text` is more than `0` or not null... any idea how to do it?

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);

cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", chkmkn2.Text);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jumlah", txtBasoC.Text); //if this textbox.text is > 0 this command should run
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalHarga", TbasoC);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: more than 0 or not null is contradicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just check if it's greater than 0:

```
int value;
bool validValue = int.TryParse(txtBasoC.Text, out value) && value > 0;
if(!validValue)
{
    // prompt the user to do it right
    return;
}
```

It's important to always pass the correct type when you use `AddWithValue`. Don't let the database do the conversion for you, that can lead to wrong results or cause performance issues.

```
// ...
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jumlah", value);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the data validation properties for the text boxes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms

A little more effort than what was posted above, but it allows you to apply the validation to several different fields!